# Issue with iOS Progressive Web App Behavior

Tags: javascript, php, html, ios, progressive-web-apps

I have developed a website that functions well, and I'm trying to enhance the user experience by allowing it to behave like a standalone app when added to the home screen on mobile devices. I have successfully implemented a manifest file, and it works seamlessly on Android devices, opening the entire site as an app.

However, on iOS, I'm encountering an issue. While the login page, created using Bootstrap, behaves like an app, the index page (mostly hardcoded) does not open as an app. I'm seeking assistance on how to resolve this discrepancy on iOS devices. Any insights or suggestions on how to make the entire site behave consistently as a Progressive Web App (PWA) on iOS would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to update my iOS device and subsequently executed the website, but unfortunately, the issue persists. In contrast, I tested the website on an Android device, and everything functioned as expected. Thank you!

[Ios behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWI2P.jpg)

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` in your html head section?

Comment: i added it now, but the ios version still looks the same as the picture i posted above.